# Как вывести ноль перед числом С++

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    int a,b,c,abc;
    std::cin>>abc;
    a=(abc/3600)%24;
    b=((abc/60)%60)%60;
    c=(abc%60)%60;
    std::cout<<a<<":"<<b<<":"<<c;
    return 0;
}
```

дано число в секундах(например 127900) нужно вывести это число в минутах часах и секундах. Выводит правильно но без нулей спереди. Как подправить этот код что бы при a,b,c <10 выводило число с нулем спереди.

Answer (score 1):

Выводите число n как

```
cout << setfill('0') << setw(2) << n;
```

Т.е. ширина вывода - 2 знака, недостающее дополнить нулями...

Comment: это через иф делать верно?

Comment: Зачем? Если будет двузначное число, оно просто не будет ничем дополнено.

Comment: а понял, просто я не сильно разбираюсь в сетфилах и не пользывался ими никогда, спасибо!

Comment: Ну, если ответ устроил - примите его, как система позволит (птица слева).

Comment: пишет через 9 минут